# how to convert a list to list of lists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, filters, array

I'm trying to turn a list into a list of lists. In this case I have a list similar to the following:
a = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
and I would like to separate the same items for another list, like:
a = [[1, 1, 1] ; [2] ; [3, 3]]

```
 let b = this.a.filter((element, index) => {
                 return this.a.indexOf(element) === index;
             });
```

I tried using splice and filter, but without success.
I was only able to create a list with different values... b=[1,2,3]
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, including the experimental (generally unsupported) [`group()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group) method.

One simple solution is to use `reduce()`, something like this, to iterate over the array and construct a new, nested one:

```javascript
let a = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 ];
let b = a.reduce(
    (acc, each) => {
        let index = acc.length - 1;
        if (acc.length && acc[index][0] == each) {
            acc[index].push(each);
        } else {
            acc.push([each]);
        }
        return acc;
    },
    []
);

// Yields [[1,1,1],[2],[3,3]]
```

Comment: Haha, yeah, many ways indeed :D

Comment: @sfdcfox your solution is lovely but took me a couple of minutes to work out! Love the use of comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

For normal browsers, you probably want `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```
let group = (values) =>
Object.values(  // Convert { a: b } to just [b]
  values.reduce(
    (p, v) => ( // p = previous value, v = next value
      (p[v] ||= []), // Assign p[v] a new array if not yet set
      p[v].push(v), // Add v to this array
      p), // Return p for next iteration
    {}) // Initial state object for reduce
);
```

Which will return an Array of arrays with all the same value.

```
let source = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
group(source); // [[1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

There's are two experimental methods called Array.prototype.group and Array.prototype.groupToMap that would fundamentally output the same results (`{ 1: [1,1,1], 2: [2], 3: [3,3,3] }`), but isn't available without polyfills except in Firefox Nightly, so you're better off having a handy function like this if you find yourself needing this sort of grouping often.